# Deserialize json result with in a json without a class or any datatype

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-5.0, c#-5.0

I have a table like this

ID     Reid    User ID     Filter 
23  1   0   [{'Vehicle':'5010','Users':'2279'}]

I am retrieving the filter column in json
and it looks like this  **"Filter": "[{'Vehicle':'5010','Users':'2279'}]"**

I am retrieving this {[Filter, [{'Vehicle':'5010','Users':'2279'}]]}
i want De serialize so that i can only get the Vehicle means 5010 and Users means 2279.

How can i get this in c#

Comment: are you familiar with Json.Net Library? it should do the trick for you, and of the top of my head you can create an object that will store the data from the json string (give the variables same names as the one in the json string) so you can deserialize to it.

Comment: yes i am familiar i think you didn't understand my question
i am getting data in json and within it has one json like type and i want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your JSON looks like?

```
{"Filter": "[{'Vehicle':'5010','Users':'2279'}]"}
```

OR

```
[{'Vehicle':'5010','Users':'2279'}]
```

OR

```
 {[Filter, [{'Vehicle':'5010','Users':'2279'}]]}
```

???

For example you could try something like this:

```
//JSON looks like this {"Filter": "[{'Vehicle':'5010','Users':'2279'}]"}
var json = "{\"Filter\": \"[{'Vehicle':'5010','Users':'2279'}]\"}";
dynamic myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
dynamic myFilterObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myObject.Filter.ToString());
int Vehicle = myFilterObject[0].Vehicle;
```

If you deserialize your json you first get an object (myObject) with one property "Filter" and a value of type string that contains another json. So just deserialize that json again.You then get another object (myFilterObject) with an Array of objects. In the exmaple i select the first object of that Array ([0]) and then get the value of "Vehicle".

Comment: your code giving me this error
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Filter'

Comment: i am retrieving this data 
{
  "Filter": "[{'Vehicle':'5012,3072','Users':'2279,2373,2374,2376'}]"
}

Comment: is there any problem in spaces or something like because it cant find the Filter word